# Pentaho Spoon - Output to multiple files based on field content

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I have been attempting splitting the results of a pentaho transform into multiple files based on the value of a specific field without any luck.

E.g. a result set containing the following:

SURNAME, FIRSTNAME, COUNTRY

Obama, Barack, USA

Cameron, David, UK

Blair, Tony, UK

Would result in 2 output files being created:

USA.txt - containing Obama's details and UK.txt - containing the other 2 rows

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can construct a field act as output filename based on Country field. Sent the new constructed field as output filenames in "Text File Output" step.

See the flow screenshot below :

[image]

You can also download the solution file from here http://pentaho.phi-integration.com/kettle/kettle-files.

Hope this helps...

Dino

Comment: Thanks again dino, that looks great. Are you able to suggest a way that i could output to different directories for each also? eg output to C:/UK/UK.txt etc dynamically? seems i cannot create the directories in the output file step, i can see the create directory step available at the job level, but its not much use to me there..

Comment: Sure, you can now download the new version of .ktr from the same link : http://pentaho.phi-integration.com/kettle/kettle-files. Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Hi again dino - just a quick followup question... what is the purpose of the "Delay Row" step in the revised solution? I've taken it out and it seems to still work perfectly. Thanks (yet again). Tom

Comment: The links given are no longer active @t_barbz can you please share the ktr - also is the process efficient if the input is say, 20m records(32 cores, 60G xmx)?

Comment: Hi @ringbearer, I'm afraid I dont think I have the files anymore. We were only looking at Pentaho as a POC and didnt take it any further in the end so I'm not able to comment about the performance either sorry. Tom

Comment: Hi @ringbearer, I have move the page here:

https://sites.google.com/a/phi-integration.com/pentaho-open-source-business-intelligence/kettle/kettle-files

Sorry for the incovenience. 20 million records should be fine.

Comment: How can i download a file, that resides with in the endpoint folder, using a button click?