# Pentaho Spoon - Wait for File - Wildcards

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I know i've asked a couple of pentaho related questions lately but am rushing to evaluate it in a short timeframe :)

My latest obstacle I am trying to overcome is that I am building a job that will process an input file when it arrives, but i only know the format for the filename, not the exact filename itself and the "wait for file" step does not allow wildcards. This seems like a glaring ommision for such a step so am wondering if i've just missed something but on forums etc it seems i'm not the only one facing such a challenge.

Ideally i need the "wait for file" step to search on a wildcard/regex and when it finds a match pass the resulting files name to the next step in the job for processing.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again I try to answer your question.

Actually, you don't need a job to wait for a file. Based on my answer on country split : [Pentaho Spoon - Output to multiple files based on field content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127485/pentaho-spoon-output-to-multiple-files-based-on-field-content/6141047#6141047), you just need to pass through the source name and then archive it using process file (see the pic below).
[image: Text Input Dialog]

From here, I think you can adapting my logic using the ktr I provided before (http://pentaho.phi-integration.com/kettle/kettle-files/split_countries.ktr).

Then you can control the repetition of the job (wait and process files) using job scheduler (see the pic).
[image]

Well, hope this helps Tom !

Regards,

Dino

Comment: Hi again dino! The "include filename in output" is just to pass the filename down the chain though isnt it? ie in this case it would pass "World-Leaders.csv", however what if the input file is not always called that? I need to try to watch a folder and process files that match wildcards eg "*.txt" so that files with different names can be processed. thanks again. Tom

Comment: Hi Tom,Put the wild cards in the Text Input configuration, i.e. Regular Expression. Then everything should be as you want it. Hope it helps. Dino

Comment: Sure Tom, glad to be helpful. Regards, Dino.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement, and solved this by creating a directory specifically for receiving the files (from a remote host).

The the "Get File Names" step reads the files in the directory and passes the name to the next step. The "Get File Names" allows wildcards, btw.

(Off course, I have to clean up in input queue once I have finished processing the file.)

EDIT: I omitted to mention that you loose the "wake" functionality with the Get File Names, and you'll have to loop and schedule regular parses of the directory.