# pentaho spoon output to multiple xml files based on field content

Tags: pentaho, etl, spoon

continuation to this question
[Pentaho Spoon - Output to multiple files based on field content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127485/pentaho-spoon-output-to-multiple-files-based-on-field-content)

how to do it for "xml output" since "xml output" doesn't have
"accept filename from the field" input in its form

Comment: Would it be OK to write into temporary files first?

Answer (score 0):

Since the step doesn't accept the filename from previous fields, you can use variables to set the value.

It's a longer path, but at least it allows you to resolve it:

1. You need to create a transformation to set the filenames in the result (using the "Copy rows to result" step)
2. You need to create another transformation with "Execute for every input row" option marked. This transformation has to read from the result ("Get rows from result" step) and set the values with "Set Variables" step.
3. Finally, a third transformation should create the xml file, using the previously created variable as filename (variables are called using this structure: ${variable_name}).

You need to connect those 3 transformations with a job.